# Search through an object and get item that equals a certain key

Tags: javascript

I would like to loop through the following json and get one whose key equals an ID.

```
{
    "519c5056af2863f1d0341788357ebb81": {
        "downloadUrl": "2F519c5056af2863f1d0341788357ebb81%2F519c5056af2863f1d0341788357ebb81?alt=media&token=f50d9b0f-579a-4c81-b12b-35ee7e6810e2",
        "file_dislikes": 0,
        "file_likes": 0,
        "file_status": "Public",
        "filename": "Another testing video",
        "upload_date": "2016-09-03T04:48:04.283Z",
        "user_id": "14nWy7qG6vN7rNdquzZNhX1QvbH2",
        "video_avatar": "./images/video.jpg"
    },
    "99eed0bcc07d23f828c44c1721433c69": {
        "downloadUrl": "2F99eed0bcc07d23f828c44c1721433c69%2F99eed0bcc07d23f828c44c1721433c69?alt=media&token=d9251647-567e-49df-b0da-d9525e10ed0e",
        "file_dislikes": 0,
        "file_likes": 0,
        "file_status": "Public",
        "filename": "Zac Brown Band - Sweet Annie ",
        "upload_date": "2016-09-03T04:22:06.285Z",
        "user_id": "14nWy7qG6vN7rNdquzZNhX1QvbH2",
        "video_avatar": "./images/video.jpg"
    }
}
```

I want to get the item whose key equals `519c5056af2863f1d0341788357ebb81` so I can display it in my html like  video.filename, video.video_avatar.

Comment: first, that's not  json, that's a plain ol' vanilla javascript object ... which has keys, like `519c5056af2863f1d0341788357ebb81` - so `obj['519c5056af2863f1d0341788357ebb81']` will reference the one you want (assuming the javscript object name is obj in this example)

Comment: can you remove the JSON tag please and the angluar this question has nothing to do with either as @JaromandaX pointed out this is plain javascript

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX. Though u sound angry to see such a question :). Well, your comment worked out. You can move it to answer so I accept it as an answer.

Comment: nah - how can written words "sound angry" ... I always type like this :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate through JSON-object

```
jQuery.each(json, function(key, value) { 
    if (key == "519c5056af2863f1d0341788357ebb81") {
        console.log(value);
    }
} );
```

To access a field of a plain JS object you can just use `[]`

```
 console.log(object["519c5056af2863f1d0341788357ebb81"]);
```

Comment: really? not just access  `json['519c5056af2863f1d0341788357ebb81']` directly? - and please don't encourage the use of the phrase json in this case - it's not json, json is a string